# Posting to ElasticSearch using Lambda vs Firehose with CloudWatch subscription filter

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm currently looking into real time processing of CloudWatch logs. We are generating around 30-40GB of logs per day (API Gateway full request/response) and have around ~100 requests/second of average. Ultimately we would like to process the logs to extract statistics from query strings as well as response headers and post the results to ElasticSearch, or S3.

I'm currently looking at two options and struggling to understand what the difference would be between these options

Create a CloudWatch subscription filter with Lambda function destination. Process data in the Lambda and post to ElasticSearch/S3.

Create a CloudWatch subscription filter and subscribe from a Firehose destination. Use a Lambda transformation function to extract the data, put it back into the stream and let Firehose post the data to ElasticSearch/S3.

The subscription filter will basically pass on records containing "Method request body before transformations" and "Endpoint response headers:" for further processing.

I don't have any insight into how the triggering of a Lambda function from a CloudWatch subscription filter would happen. Is there any batching involved, or will it be triggered for every single log event passed by the subscription filter? On the contrary I DO understand that Firehose does offer batching, which I can control to some extent.

Can someone offer advice on this? Are there any other options that I might have overlooked? Appreciate any input.

Comment: The Elastic Stack 6.5 has been released on Nov 14th and a new beat called [Functionbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/functionbeat-overview.html) allows you to stream your Cloudwatch logs easily to ES.

Comment: I am currently in the same situation. Did you conclude on one of the above options? Which and Why?

Comment: We went with firehose. I had some disucssions with AWS support, and as I recall they said that was the way to go for this kind of load.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the cloudwatch logs with amazon kinesis streams using subscription filters. In this way, whenever a new log matches the subscription filter it is appended to your kinesis stream.
Once your logs are located in Kinesis streams you have a lot of options. For example you can send them to Kinesis Firehose Delivery Streams and probably transform them using a Datatransformation lambda or directly to Elastic Search e.t.c.

Assuming that you already have cloudwatch logs and a kinesis stream , the cloudformation resource you need is the following:

```
  KinesisToCloudwatchSubscription:
    Type: AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter
    Properties:
      DestinationArn: !GetAtt [your_kinesis_stream, Arn]
      FilterPattern: your_cloudwatch_logstream
      RoleArn: A role that permits the "kinesis:PutRecord" action
      LogGroupName:  "/aws/lambda/your_lambda_function"
```